# Use local gateway for internet access, but stil have the vnet accessable, tun interface

Tags: routing, openvpn

I did setup a OpenVPN server on a Fedora 20 VPS, I can connect to the server itself and its services via the vnet just fine.

```
# +<tun>+       VNET     <tun>-<eth> +------------+
# | VPS |--[10.8.0.0/24]--|CLIENT|---|  LAN       |
# +-----+                 +------+   +------------+
#                                    192.168.178.0/24
```

But as soon as the OpenVPN client gets started, a new `default` route is pushed to the client. This in turn causes some mess as I now have a wrong default gateway which does obviously not work, as all request which are not destined for the LAN are now being (tried to be routed) through the `VNET` (via its gateway):

```
# ip route list
default via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 proto static metric 1024
192.168.178.0/24 dev eth0 ....
....
```

However, a simpe set of route delete and route add

```
ip route del default via 10.8.0.1
ip route add default via 192.168.178.1
ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0
```

makes everything work again, as ( I guess that is the reason) only one default route remains and the `10.8.0.0/24` subnet gets routed via the `tun0` interface.

**What changes do I need to make that I can have access to internet via the local gatway, but still access services in my private virtual network without having to change the routes manually?**

```
port 1194
dev tun

tls-server 
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh1024.pem

mode server

# the addresses which represent the server
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2

# pool of IPs to assign to clients
ifconfig-pool 10.8.0.66 10.8.0.99

#### routing info that gets pushed from server to client
#### so this represents the subnet that gets routed
#### through the tap0 interface
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"

#### do I need any of these? don't think so
####
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
#push "dhcp-option WINS 8.8.8.8"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.1"
#push "dhcp-option WINS 192.168.0.1"

keepalive 10 60

inactive 600

#### what should I set this to?
#### the routing from server => client   
#### so this should include all IPs we assign
#### to the clients
route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0

user openvpn
group openvpn

persist-tun
persist-key

client-to-client

verb 4
```

Note: I do not want to make the traffic go through the server (and thus go through the vnet), but get resolved by local router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `NetworkManager` with its `OpenVPN-client` program yields a checkbox to only use the network for resources **within** that network (network here refers to `10.8.0.0/24`). This not a proper fix on the serverside which I desire, but I guess good enough.

---

`Networking > Editing foo-vpn`

Select `IPv4` or `IPv6` tab, whatever you need. Select `Routes...` and check `Use this connection only for resources on its network`